# How do I do the equivalent of getClassLoader().getResources() in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, classpath

I have an `IJavaProject` and I need to locate resources on the classpath of this project, i.e. the equivalent of `getClassLoader().getResources()` (note: This call returns `Enumeration<URL>` instead of a single `URL`).

How do I examine the classpath of a Java project from a Eclipse bundle/plug-in, for example to find all classpath entries which contain `log4j.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getPackageFragmentRoots()` to get the equivalent of entries in the classpath. For each of the roots, you can call `getNonJavaResources()` to get the non-java things under that root and you can call `getChildren()` recursively to get the children (in a java hierarchy kind of way).  Eventually those indirectly traversed children will be java source files which you can confirm by sending them the `getUnderlyingResource()` method.

Here is some code:

```
private Collection<String> keys( IJavaProject project, String[] bundleNames ) throws CoreException, IOException {

    Set<String> keys = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

    for( String bundleName : bundleNames ) {

        IPath path = new Path( toResourceName( bundleName ) );

        boolean found = false;

        IPackageFragmentRoot[] packageFragmentRoots = project.getPackageFragmentRoots();
        for( IPackageFragmentRoot root : packageFragmentRoots ) {
            found |= collectKeys( root, path, keys );
        }

        if( ! found ) {
            throw new BundleNotFoundException( bundleName );
        }
    }

    return keys;
}

private boolean collectKeys( IPackageFragmentRoot root, IPath path, Set<String> keys ) throws CoreException, IOException {
    IPath fullPath = root.getPath().append( path );
    System.out.println( "fullPath=" + fullPath );

    IFile file = root.getJavaProject().getProject().getFile( fullPath.removeFirstSegments( 1 ) );
    System.out.println( "file=" + fullPath );

    if( ! file.exists() ) {
        return false;
    }

    log.debug( "Loading " + file );

    InputStream stream = file.getContents( true );
    try {
        Properties p = load( file.getFullPath().toString(), stream );

        keys.addAll( keySet( p ) );
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }

    return true;
}

protected String toResourceName( String bundleKey ) {

    String path = bundleKey.replace( '.', '/' );
    return path + ".properties";
}
```

Comment: That looks like it will work if the file you're looking for is on the file system.  If it's in a jar on the classpath I don't know that you'd find it this way.  You might have to use getNonJavaResources() on the fragment root.

Comment: ah, yes. When I come to it, I'll update the code to work with JARs as well (they would return `IStorage` instead of `IFile`).